# How I find out which files wicket write in the "generated" directory?

Tags: payara, wicket-1.6

I'm new in wicket. But I have to care a project with wicket 6.20 components (run on a payara application server). Now I have a space problem on my live-server. In directory

```
payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/my-ear-21628-LIVE-CLUSTER/my-web_war/wicket.my-web-filestore
```

web-filestore are collect in time a huge amount of data files.

```
./7857
./7857/9907
./7857/9907/6cb5a7b9cb89ad9e0d8b1422af63
./7857/9907/6cb5a7b9cb89ad9e0d8b1422af63/data
./7857/1851
./7857/1851/6bc6a644f4ab91a7674b0e91b4fe
./7857/1851/6bc6a644f4ab91a7674b0e91b4fe/data
...
```

How can I find the cause of this file generation?

Answer (score 1):

Wicket stores the stateful pages on the disk (by default). It creates a file for each http session. On session expiration the file is deleted and the content of the temp folder should not grow endlessly.
But there was a bug in the past that left such files there.
I don't remember in which version exactly the bug was fixed.

The best would be to upgrade to the latest available version. 6.x is not supported since several years, but still you can upgrade to latest 6.x.

Comment: Thanks! Hard job to upgrade for me. But your explanation seems logical.